# Android WebView doesn't respect locked rotation orientation

Tags: android, webview, landscape-portrait, screen-rotation

I have an Android app which consists mainly of a WebView that wraps a website.

If I lock the orientation of my phone into portrait mode lets say, when I open the app, the website within the WebView doesn't respect the locked portrait orientation. Instead if I hold the phone vertically, the website display in portrait mode as expect... BUT as I turn the phone horizontally, instead of staying in portrait mode, the website switches to landscape mode.

How can I fix this? I imagine that the WebView screen size is updating as the phone is rotating from vertical to horizontal, and so the website reorients itself... despite the over android phone being locked in portrait mode. Why does the WebView still tell the website the screensize has changed? How do I prevent this?

Comment: What version of WebView?  It should be listed under Settings > Apps.

Comment: Well its Android 4.1.2 / API 16+. Where would I find the specific version of WebView within System Settings > Apps?

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure.  On newer Android versions, "Android System WebView" is listed as an installed app.

Comment: What exactly are you doing to lock the orientation?  It sounds like that's not actually working the way you expect.  The default behavior for Android activities is to change orientation like you are describing.

Comment: I'm locking the orientation as an overall system setting of the device, so that no apps or homescreen can go into landscape mode. Every other app respects that portrait landscape when the overall system is locked in portrait except for the WebView in my specific app.